# Create a Devexpress ASP.net core project as docker in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, docker, devexpress, visual-studio-2019

I like to start a new WEB UI project based on a Devexpress template, starting the project from the template gallery of Devexpress. Since there is no "docker support" option during the creation process, how do I containerize this project?

I already worket with asp.net core projects, but there I had the option for docker-support and Visual studio did everything on it's own.

Any experiences?

Greetings

Comment: This page explains how to 'dockerize' any ASP.NET Core application: https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/.

Comment: Thank you, this is how it works. I figured out the answer.

Comment: Solution: Follow the description from @amartynov s comment. For devexpress you will get another problem. Devexpress tries to get dependencies from private repositories, which are not available in your docker build flow... for this, you have to pass this repos to docker. If the libs are local, create an own private repo or include them to your project.